# Edit Maven Compiled Repository Source Code

Tags: java, android, maven, compilation

I am using a maven repository from here:

https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

The dependency is:

```
compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.2.3'
```

And there is a bug in their source code I need to fix. However when I open the class, the method is pre-compiled code and I can't change it.

```
public void onInitialized() { /* compiled code */ }
```

Do you know how I can make changes to this locally (even if I have to point the dependency to a path on my computer thats fine, but how would I do something like that?

**Update**

Here is the github project folder structure when I open it up in Android Studio. There is a library folder that I want to turn into an aar.

[image]

Comment: you cannot do modification locally, but you can do if you download that lib and add in your project ad module.

Answer (score 1):

Since the source code is available there is no need to mess around too much.

If you cannot work around your issue by extending the class you can clone the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage.git
```

then change the version in `gradle.properties` into *1.2.3-agressorpatch1* (as an example) to distinguish the artifact from the original one. Then change the sources you want to have changed and compile the project:

```
gradle clean assemble
```

The project is apache licensed so that is perfectly ok.

The jar that is created needs to end up in a maven repository. Either copy it locally to ~/.m2/repository (or where the maven repo is located at) or a folder keeping the same structure.

```
file:///sharedfolder/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage/gpuimage-library/1.2.3-agressorpatch1/gpuimage-library-1.2.3-agressorpatch1.aar
```

The link you posted is a source repository, not a maven repository.

So you need to tell your build to use this location as well. I'm not good with gradle but it will look like:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "file:///sharedfolder"
    }
}
```

This saves you to manually decompile the class and re-pack the artifact and so on.

Comment: Thanks I will investigate your solution in the near future!

Comment: One question though, you said it was a source repository not a Maven one, but without `repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}` my code fails because it says it `cant find jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.2.3`. So isn't this a Maven Central repository after all? If so I assume Im going to create a local version instead right?

Comment: yep. maven central is the default repository where maven finds artifacts. You can search an browse its contents here: http://search.maven.org - so that is needed for the artifact to download the jar you use as a dependency. You stated "I am using a maven repository from here:
https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage" so I thought you use that url as repository url (which would not work). Maybe you meant you use the artifact from there? So anyway: you need maven central for dependencies. The new artifact you create should have a new version to not overlap with an existing artifact.

Comment: So I've update the question a bit. When I open the github source project, there is actually the library I want, but its added as a sub-module(?) in the project. Is there a way to just isolate that library module (which has all the java code) and compile that into an aar file?

Comment: Srry I'm not much of a gradle or android developer. The library folder looks pretty much self-contained: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/tree/master/library - there is a gradle.build file in it. So if you're in the folder and execute the gradle build something will come out? It looks like it will create a jar (not sure). If you copy or have that folder in your project the same thing should happen (its Apache Licensed, only keep the license headers intact, so thats ok). How to get to an aar file: I have no idea :)

Comment: what about maven?